# The text in the columns of a table to be aligned to the right

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx, columns, text

I have a table defined as

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[man]{apa}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage[dviwin]{graphicx}
\linespread{1.6}
\title{}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \caption{British Open 2012 (round 2): Hole score frequencies and estimated values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ for round 2 (N = 156, 2: two strokes needed, 3: three strokes needed, etc.).}
    \label{tab:2}      
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}   {p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}}
\hline
   &   &   & \multicolumn{9}{c}{hole score} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{parameter}\\
\hline
Hole &  length & par & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & $\hat{p}$ & $\hat{q}$ & $\hat{r}$\\
\hline
 1 & 205 & 3 & 21 & 117 & 17 & 1 &   &   &      &   &   &        .076 & .049 & -.005 \\
 2 & 481 & 4 & 1 & 20 & 104 & 30 & 1 &   &     &   &   &        .065 & .074 & -.021 \\
 3 & 478 & 4 &   & 11 & 79 & 51 & 14 & 1 &     &   &   &        .072 & .168 & -.062 \\
 4 & 392 & 4 &   & 18 & 115 & 20 & 2 & 1 &     &   &   &        .044 & .044 & .001 \\
 5 & 219 & 3 & 22 & 114 & 18 & 2 &   &   &     &   &   &        .078 & .053 & -.001 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want the text in the columns to be aligned to the right. How can I do that?

Comment: `>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.8cm}`.

Comment: Personally, I would recomment using `S` type coluns from the `siunitx` package.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following redesign based on `siunitx` and `booktabs` or `tabular*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
    \caption{British Open 2012 (round 2): Hole score frequencies and estimated values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ for round 2 (N = 156, 2: two strokes needed, 3: three strokes needed, etc.).}
    \label{tab:2} 
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}     
    \sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3] c *{9}{S[table-format=3]} *{3}{S[table-format=-.3]}}
\toprule
   &   &   & \multicolumn{9}{c}{hole score} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{parameter}\\
\cmidrule(r){4-12} \cmidrule(l){13-15}
{Hole} &  {length} & {par} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & {$\hat{p}$} & {$\hat{q}$} & {$\hat{r}$}\\
\midrule
 1 & 205 & 3 & 21 & 117 & 17 & 1 &   &   &      &   &   &        .076 & .049 & -.005 \\
 2 & 481 & 4 & 1 & 20 & 104 & 30 & 1 &   &     &   &   &        .065 & .074 & -.021 \\
 3 & 478 & 4 &   & 11 & 79 & 51 & 14 & 1 &     &   &   &        .072 & .168 & -.062 \\
 4 & 392 & 4 &   & 18 & 115 & 20 & 2 & 1 &     &   &   &        .044 & .044 & .001 \\
 5 & 219 & 3 & 22 & 114 & 18 & 2 &   &   &     &   &   &        .078 & .053 & -.001 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


    \begin{table}[!h]
\centering
    \caption{British Open 2012 (round 2): Hole score frequencies and estimated values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ for round 2 (N = 156, 2: two strokes needed, 3: three strokes needed, etc.).}
    \label{tab:2} 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}     
    \sisetup{add-integer-zero=false}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{12}{r}*{3}{>{$}r<{$}}}
\toprule
   &   &   & \multicolumn{9}{c}{hole score} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{parameter}\\
\cmidrule(r){4-12} \cmidrule(l){13-15}
{Hole} &  {length} & {par} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & \hat{p} & \hat{q} & \hat{r}\\
\midrule
 1 & 205 & 3 & 21 & 117 & 17 & 1 &   &   &      &   &   &        .076 & .049 & -.005 \\
 2 & 481 & 4 & 1 & 20 & 104 & 30 & 1 &   &     &   &   &        .065 & .074 & -.021 \\
 3 & 478 & 4 &   & 11 & 79 & 51 & 14 & 1 &     &   &   &        .072 & .168 & -.062 \\
 4 & 392 & 4 &   & 18 & 115 & 20 & 2 & 1 &     &   &   &        .044 & .044 & .001 \\
 5 & 219 & 3 & 22 & 114 & 18 & 2 &   &   &     &   &   &        .078 & .053 & -.001 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing few things -- scriptsize becos table is too wide -- captio removed the Table label has to be made scriptsize by changing macro -- Hole abbreviated to Ho and length to lth -- can be changed again by OP to liking -- the caption can be put as a row above or below added to the table

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[man]{apa}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,array}
\usepackage[dviwin]{graphicx}
%\linespread{1.6}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.65cm}@{}}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
        \scriptsize
    { Table1: British Open 2012 (round 2): Hole score frequencies and estimated values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ for round 2 (N = 156, 2: two strokes needed, 3: three strokes needed, etc.).}
    \label{tab:2}      
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}   {RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR}
%   {p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}}
\hline
   &   &   & \multicolumn{9}{c}{hole score} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{parameter}\\
\hline
Ho &  lth & par & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & $\hat{p}$ & $\hat{q}$ & $\hat{r}$\\
\hline
 1 & 205 & 3 & 21 & 117 & 17 & 1 &   &   &      &   &   &        .076 & .049 & -.005 \\
 2 & 481 & 4 & 1 & 20 & 104 & 30 & 1 &   &     &   &   &        .065 & .074 & -.021 \\
 3 & 478 & 4 &   & 11 & 79 & 51 & 14 & 1 &     &   &   &        .072 & .168 & -.062 \\
 4 & 392 & 4 &   & 18 & 115 & 20 & 2 & 1 &     &   &   &        .044 & .044 & .001 \\
 5 & 219 & 3 & 22 & 114 & 18 & 2 &   &   &     &   &   &        .078 & .053 & -.001 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\documentclass[man]{apa}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,array}
\usepackage[dviwin]{graphicx}
%\linespread{1.6}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.65cm}@{}}
\title{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
        \scriptsize
%    { Table1: British Open 2012 (round 2): Hole score frequencies and estimated values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ for round 2 (N = 156, 2: two strokes needed, 3: three strokes needed, etc.).}
    \label{tab:2}      
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}   {RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR}
%   {p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}p{0.8cm}}
\hline
   &   &   & \multicolumn{9}{c}{hole score} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{parameter}\\
\hline
Ho &  lth & par & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & $\hat{p}$ & $\hat{q}$ & $\hat{r}$\\
\hline
 1 & 205 & 3 & 21 & 117 & 17 & 1 &   &   &      &   &   &        .076 & .049 & -.005 \\
 2 & 481 & 4 & 1 & 20 & 104 & 30 & 1 &   &     &   &   &        .065 & .074 & -.021 \\
 3 & 478 & 4 &   & 11 & 79 & 51 & 14 & 1 &     &   &   &        .072 & .168 & -.062 \\
 4 & 392 & 4 &   & 18 & 115 & 20 & 2 & 1 &     &   &   &        .044 & .044 & .001 \\
 5 & 219 & 3 & 22 & 114 & 18 & 2 &   &   &     &   &   &        .078 & .053 & -.001 \\ \hline
 \multicolumn{16}{l}{Table1: British Open 2012 (round 2): Hole score frequencies and estimated}\\
 \multicolumn{16}{l}{ values for $p$, $q$ and $r$ for round 2 (N = 156, 2: two strokes needed, }\\
 \multicolumn{16}{l}{3: three strokes needed, etc.).}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest manually numbering the table ("Table1: British Open 2012...") instead of using the usual `\caption` approach that was already usedin in the code in the question? Also did you test the `\label`  - `\ ref` mechanism with your manually numbered tables?

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help. Finally, I want to align the text in the first column to the right. Thanks in advance.